# PageView animateToPage on mouse scroll event in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I tried to use jumpToPage on mouse scroll event, and I succeeded. But there's now 2 problems.
The jumpToPage is too fast and I'd like to make it a little bit slower, the second problem is there's a white background (which doesn't load on the browser, and the last page snaps back to it's place).

For the first problem I tried to use animateToPage, without any success. And for the second problem, I used an if condition so the index won't exceed the page count, without any success also.

Here's my code:

```
    Listener(
      onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
        if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) {
          if (pointerSignal.scrollDelta.dy > 0) {
            if(_index < 4) {
              int newIndex = _index + 1;
              pageController.jumpToPage(newIndex);
              // pageController.animateToPage(
              //   newIndex, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeIn
              // );
              print(newIndex);
            }
          } 
          else 
          {
            // pageController.jumpToPage(_index - 1);
          }
        }
      },
      child: PageView(
        controller: pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        pageSnapping: true,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          _index = index;
        },
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.green,
          )
        ]
      ),
    )
```

You can see here that I used animateToPage and I hashed it. And I also hashed the jumpToPage in the else statement for testing purposes.

So, my question is, how to address the 2 problems I mentioned?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue comes from the way you are using your `_index` variable. As you are changing the value of `_index` both in your `onPointerSignal` and in your `onPageChanged` both values might conflict.

Here's how I've tried implementing your code:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int _index = 0;
  final pageController = PageController();
  final _animationDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 500);
  final _curve = Curves.easeIn;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
        if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) {
          if (pointerSignal.scrollDelta.dy > 0) {
            pageController.nextPage(
                curve: _curve, duration: _animationDuration);
          } else {
            pageController.previousPage(
                duration: _animationDuration, curve: _curve);
          }
        }
      },
      child: PageView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          controller: pageController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          pageSnapping: true,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            _index = index;
          },
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.red),
            Container(color: Colors.blue),
            Container(color: Colors.green)
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

[Test the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/30dd52646eadeb5e3ec7256760756a35?null_safety=true)

Basically I'm not depending on the `_index` variable and instead using the methods `nextPage` and `previousPage` to manage the pageview indexation.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I tried your solution, the next page does appear, but it takes several mouse scrolls and it jitters with the first few scrolls..
Is there a way to use animateToPage and make it smooth?
Thanks again...

Comment: Just fixed my code sample, the issue was that the default gesture from PageView was overlapping with the `Listener`, which does impact the scrolling using the mouse scroll but not with the trackpad. I've fixed it by adding `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to the `PageView`. By doing so it works as intended with the mouse scroll.